# Calling child runbook results in The term '.\RunbookName.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, hybrid-runbook-worker

I am trying to do POC on working with child runbooks. As part of this POC I created a simple runbook Child.ps1 with below content:

```
Param(
    [string]$FolderPath
)
$path = $FolderPath
if(! (Test-Path $path))
{
    New-Item -Type dir -Path $path
    Write-Output "Created directory '$path'"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Directory '$path' already exists"
}
```

and a Parent Runbook, which calls the child runbook by passing the parameter as shown below:

```
.\Child.ps1 -FolderPath "C:\TestPath"
```

When I test the parent runbook I get following error:

```
.\Child.ps1 : The term '.\Child.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Child.ps1 -FolderPath "C:\TestPath"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\Child.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am trying to test this using Hybrid Worker. I am able to successfully test the child runbook. Any ideas why this is failing. AM I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this should work. However, you may get this error message if the child runbook is not published. Is it published?

Comment: The child runbook was not published. I published it and after that, it worked.